# Vagrant script not booting -provisioning issue

Tags: vagrant

This script works when I load it in vagrant

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Box Settings
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  
  # Provider Settings
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = 2048
    vb.cpus = 4
  end

  # # Network Settings 
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # # Folder Settings 
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html", :mount_options => ["dmode=777",
    "fmode=777"] 


  # # Provision Settings 
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

However when I try to uncomment the provisions so it reads:

## # Provision Settings

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

```
apt-get update

apt-get install -y apache2
```

SHELL

end

It then refuses to reload using the vagrant reload command the powershell console says:

```
default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
```

""Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.  ""

I have no idea why it doesn't like that  bit of code?

Answer (score 0):

first enable `vb.gui= true` in your vagrant file .
Once you execute vagrant up command , you will be able to see the error thrown by the box.
In my case, it was -
 `kernel panic - not syncing: attemped to kill idle task!`
If this error is thrown

- just go to settings and search turn windows feature on or off .
- Untick Virtual Machine platform and then restart your pc.
  This will help.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksjmG.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR6uT.png